# How to disable/enable input field when it is clicked in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, disabled-input, input-field

I have an input field that I am trying to disabled and enabled when the input field is clicked. So for example, disabled input field should be shown as default and when inside of the input field is clicked, it should be enabled again and when outside of the input field is clicked again, the input field should be disabled.

So for this my input field is:

```
<input id="cart_amount" type="number" min="1" class="col-1 form-control cart-input" v-model="item.amount" :disabled="disabled">
```

And my functions for this:

```
data() {
        return {
            disabled: true,
        };
    },
    computed: {
        isDisabled() {
            return !this.disabled;
        },
}
```

But even this isDisabled function, I cannot make the input field disabled and I don't know how I can make enabled/disabled when clicked/unclicked input field.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: is it possible to solve it with a extra button?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a good UX. Disabled state means that input is not clickable, focusable.

Comment: It doesnt need to be disabled state, if you have a better view please suggest me @zooly

Comment: so basically you don't want user to input anything right ?

Comment: I want user to input but only when user click inside of the input

Comment: I think there is only two ways in which a user can type in an input, 1. clicking on the input 2. activating the input using tab key. so do you want to disable the tab key navigation in a form?

Comment: but it dosen't make sense to disable by default

Comment: So basically I want input disabled and when it is clicked it should be enabled again because I want to update my input. To do it, after outside of the input field is clicked I want to disabled the input again. Hope I am clear, and disabled state doesnt need to be used if you have better idea to do this case. I am open and looking forward for your advices./solutions.

Comment: What you describe is a simple input without enabled/disabled aspect. I don't get the point of making it disabled when it is not focused

Comment: When outside is clicked I want to make an API call and update, thats why I thought it would be a nice idea to make the input field like this

Comment: you dont need the computed function, just use the data() value.  and the computed function you have is reversing the logic.